# Using `defaults` CLI when App Group is enabled : "domain does not exist"

Tags: swift, macos, macos-catalina

I am developing a macOS app, with an embedded [Finder Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/findersync/fifindersync) and I want the app and the extension to share [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)

The App is Sandboxed for future distribution on the app store.

I followed instructions here : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1

1. Both targets are part of the same app group, as it can be seen in the Entitlements:

   ```xml
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)com.stormacq.mac.MyApp</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
    <true/>
   ```
2. I am accessing the UserDefaults by the `suiteName` :

   ```swift
   let defaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "TEAM_ID.com.stormacq.mac.MyApp")

   //where TEAM_ID is the actual team id used to sign the app (something like 123AB45CDE)
   ```

However, when trying to read or write the defaults at App startup time, I receive this error message :

> [User Defaults] Couldn't read values in
> CFPrefsPlistSource<0x600002c4d200> (Domain:
> TEAM_ID.com.stormacq.mac.MyApp, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost:
> Yes, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): Using
> kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System
> Containers, detaching from cfprefsd

I found weird that the error message says `Container: (null),`.

The group container and the shared Preference file is created (and contains the correct default values set by my code) :

```
➜  ~ ls -al ~/Library/Group\ Containers/TEAM_ID.com.stormacq.mac.MyApp/Library/Preferences/                                             
total 8
drwx------  3 stormacq  1896053708   96 Sep  6 19:58 .
drwx------  5 stormacq  1896053708  160 Sep  6 19:58 ..
-rw-------@ 1 stormacq  1896053708  103 Sep  6 19:58 TEAM_ID.com.stormacq.mac.MyApp.plist

# I edited TEAM_ID to post this message
```

I am using Xcode 11.7 (Swift 5) and macOS 10.15.6.

The shared preferences file is corrected created in `~/Library/Group Containers` directory, but the `defaults` command line does not see it.

```
➜  ~ defaults read com.stormacq.mac.MyApp
2020-09-07 10:25:53.188 defaults[82827:947786] 
Domain com.stormacq.mac.MyApp does not exist

➜  ~ defaults read TEAM_ID.com.stormacq.mac.MyApp
2020-09-07 10:26:05.088 defaults[82857:947925] 
Domain TEAM_ID.com.stormacq.mac.MyApp does not exist
```

The same with non-shared preferences works correctly.

Can `defaults` read `Group Containers` ?